# Avanti barrel/cylinder nut replacement?

Tags: seatpost, mechanical, bolt

I’m pretty sure I’ve stripped the barrel/cylinder nut on my Avanti bike’s seatpost clamp. The bolt goes in but just keeps spinning around.

Is it possible to remove the nut from inside the frame? Or any other ways to fix it?[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site - great question with a useful photo.

Comment: You might try a magnet. If that doesn't help, see @Criggie 's answer

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

[image]

More info: https://bicyclenetwork.com.au/newsroom/2020/05/21/seat-clamp-defect-triggers-avanti-recall/

This may or may not cover your bike.

---

At first look, the nuts are some kind of barrel/cylinder with a transverse hole, which is threaded for the bolt.

Something vaguely like this:

[image]

Start by searching out Avanti service manuals.  They may have the guidence you need.

If it were me and I had no other info to work from, I'd remove the two bolts, and use an angled pick to lever the nut/barrel up and out of the frame then for a better look at it.  Another option is to drill into the top and try to pull it out, but we don't know if there's a retainer.
 Also look under that area to see if there are any plugs or access holes or anything.
Remove the seatpost and look down inside the frame too.

Once you have the barrel out, it may be easy to make a new one, or you might choose to helicoil it.  Downside, there's already metal missing and helicoiling it will remove even more metal.